# find biggest index of something in c

Tags: c, indexing

I want to write a function that finds the biggest index of the character in a string. But when the index is already found once, it may not return it.
***For example***:
word: "hello"
character: `l`
indexset={};
expected return value = 3

when I do this function again:
word: "hello"
character: `l`
indexset={3};
expected return value = 2

This is how I allocated spaces for my indexset:

```
*indexset = (int*) malloc(strlen(am->transposition)*sizeof(int));
```

In my code, that's enough space for each index of each character.
My function to find the biggest index:

```
int findBiggestIndex(char karakter,char* woord,int* indexset, int *size){
    int i=0,index;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(woord);i++){
        if(karakter==woord[i] && !inArray(indexset,i,*size)){
            index=i;
            printf("%d",*size);
            indexset[*size]=index;
            (*size)++;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

And the method inArray():

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int inArray(int* arr, int a, int size){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(arr[i]==a){
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The method inArray is also declared before findBiggestIndex so that's not the problem.
Please help

Comment: Loop through in reverse.

Comment: what is the problem..?

Comment: For the character `l`, the biggest index for |h|e|l|l|o| would be 3, not 2. I am not sure what you mean by _indexset_. Is it being used to store previously found indices?  Why not simply walk through the string, comparing each position with target char, and keep an index as you go. That would meet your stated objective.  (see example below)

Answer (score 0):

*I want to write a function that finds the biggest index of the character in a string.*

If you want to find the last occurrence of a character in a string...
loop through string and compare char elements:

***Something like***:

```
int findLastIndex(char *str, char c)
{
    int keep = 0, i, len;
    if(str)
    {
        len = strlen(str);

        for(i=0;i<len ;i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == c) keep = i;   
        }
        return keep;//0 means nothing found
    }
    return -1;//means problem with input string
}

int main(void)
{
     int cnt= findLastIndex("only 1 g in line", 'g');
     //cnt should return as 7 for these inputs

         cnt= findLastIndex("2 g's in line(g)", 'g');
     //cnt should return as 14 for these inputs
     return 0;
}  

literal string arguments:  
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0|1|2|3|4|5|
|o|n|l|y| |1| |g| |i|n| |l|i|n|e|
               ^  
|2| |g|'|s| |i|n| |l|i|n|e|(|g|)|
                             ^
```

Therefore, should see index as 7 for first arg, 14 for second arg